# How to substr_replace a "$" in front of price tags using VBO

Tags: views

I'm using Views Bulk Operations to update details on a bunch of products (more than 1300 of them.)  I am trying to insert a "$" in front of the #### price tag, and I receive an error of:

> Parsing Error in script: syntax error, unexpected '"$"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Here is the PHP code I'm trying to execute. Can anyone tell me if I have typed something wrong here? I'm pretty new to this... thanks all!

```
$entity->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = substr_replace($entity->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], '$', 0, 0);
entity_save('node', $entity);
```

Comment: Are you sure that line before this one is properly ended with `;`? Also, some PHP versions didn't like it when you was trying to access object's property's indexes directly (like in `$entity->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE]`). I don't really think you are using php that old, but your php version might help.

Comment: That was my line of thought too. I checked and I'm using 5.4.32.

I thought it was having a problem with the $, so I tried "$" and '$' (the latter being the right way.) They both gave me the error.  Then I took the spaces out between commas and tried again, with some success.  I have NO idea what was actually causing the issue, because I copied and pasted the code each time to make sure my changes were consistent, and it eventually worked (as listed in my OP.)  Talk about strange!